# Trying to make Java Web Scraper

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to make java web scraper but I lost somewhere in the code
What is supposed to be done to just extract Name ,Email and phone no form the given web page and export into plain text.

I am using `jsoup` library in this too .

But cant able to figure it out how I can achieve this task

This is how my codes look like.

```
package javaapplication6;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.helper.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

import java.io.*; // Only needed if scraping a local File.

public class javaapplication6 {


    public javaapplication6() {

        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://cs.qau.edu.pk/faculty.php/").get();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
                
        Elements table = doc.getElementsByClass("tbl");
        Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("TR");
        
        for (Element row : rows) {
            Elements tds = row.getElementsByTag("TD");
            for (int i = 0; i < tds.size(); i++) {
                if (i == 1) System.out.println(tds.get(i).text());
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        new javaapplication6();
    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following code for Name & details,

The connect(String URL) method creates a new Connection, and get() fetches and parses the HTML file.

Then we find matching elements, then we use the foreach loop to retrieve name & details.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class CsDotQauDotEduPk {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://cs.qau.edu.pk/faculty.php/").get();

    Elements ele = doc.select("div.container td");
    for (Element e : ele) {

        Elements el = e.select("strong").eq(0);
        Elements e2 = e.select("td p").eq(1);

        final String name = el.text();
        final String details = e2.text();

        System.out.println(name+" >> "+ details);
    }}}
```

Output:

> Dr. Onaiza Maqbool >> Email: onaiza@qau.edu.pk Phone: +92-51-9064 2060
>
> Dr. Khalid Saleem >> Email: ksaleem@qau.edu.pk Phone: +92-51-9064 2050
>
> Dr. Shuaib Karim >> Email: skarim@qau.edu.pk Phone: +92-51-9064 2055
>
> Dr. Rabeeh Ayaz Abbasi >> Email: rabbasi@qau.edu.pk Phone: +92-51-9064
>   2050
>
> Dr. Ghazanfar Farooq >> Assistant Professor
>
> Dr. Muddassar Azam Sindhu >> Email: masindhu@qau.edu.pk Phone:
>   +92-51-9064 2066
>
> Dr. Akmal Saeed Khattak >> Email: akhattak@qau.edu.pk Phone:
>   +92-51-9064 2161
>
> Dr. Muhammad Aasim Rafique >>
>
> Dr. Umer Rasheed >>
>
> Memoona Afsheen Malik >> Email: memoona@qau.edu.pk Phone: +92-51-9064
>   2064
>
> Ifrah Farrukh Khan >> Email: (ifrahkhanqau@yahoo.com) Phone:
>   +92-51-9064 2005
>
> S. M. Naqi >> Email: smnaqi@qau.edu.pk Phone: +92-51-9064 2059

Answer (score 3):

You didn't post the HTML code here. But you can do simply like this to achieve what you need,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://cs.qau.edu.pk/faculty.php/").get();

// If there is table id you can put that below -> table[id=tableid]
for (Element table : doc.select("table[id=]")) {
     for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");
        System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + "->" + tds.get(1).text() + "->" + tds.get(2).text());
     }
}
```